# populus: How to have multiple transactions in a single block?

Tags: transactions, populus

My goal is to write a test case to simulate my contract inside `populus`. I observe that each `transaction()`(even it is a empty function call) will increment block number as one no matter what.

[Q] As we know in a single block there could be multiple transactions. Is it possible to have multiple transactions in a single block, inside the test case of populus?

test.py:

```
blkArrayIndex =  0;
gasUsed       = [];
blockNumber   = [];

set_txn_hash     = my_contract.transact().dummy(); #this is a dummy transaction.
contract_address = unmigrated_chain.wait.for_receipt(set_txn_hash)

gasUsed.append( contract_address["gasUsed"] );
blockNumber.append( contract_address["blockNumber"] );
blkArrayIndex = blkArrayIndex + 1;

set_txn_hash     = my_contract.transact().dummy(); #added line.#
set_txn_hash     = my_contract.transact().dummy(); #added line.#
set_txn_hash     = my_contract.transact().dummy(); #added line.#
set_txn_hash     = my_contract.transact().dummy(); #this is a dummy transaction.
contract_address = unmigrated_chain.wait.for_receipt(set_txn_hash);

gasUsed.append( contract_address["gasUsed"] );
blockNumber.append( contract_address["blockNumber"] );
blkArrayIndex = blkArrayIndex + 1;

for j in range(0, blkArrayIndex):
    print '%s:%d |%s: %d' % ("gasUsed", gasUsed[j], "blockNumber", blockNumber[j])
```

Output (without added lines):

```
gasUsed:222648 |blockNumber: 4
gasUsed:290051 |blockNumber: 5
```

Output (when new lines are added): block number changed from 5 to 8.

```
gasUsed:222648|blockNumber: 4
gasUsed:350051|blockNumber: 8 <= after the added lines I want block number as 5 instead of 8.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having number of transactions in a block is possible but doing it manually is not possible,
Block is created in 2 situations,

### 1.Time out period is reached.

> There is a time out period to create a block (the exact time out
>   period is unknown to me, may be 1 or 2 seconds), the transaction made
>   in-between this timeout period are kept under a single block.

### 2.Max Limitation Reached

> When we reach the max limitation of transactions to be contained in a
>   single block(max limitation is unknown to me) before the time out
>   reached , a new block is created and the transactions done after that
>   are registered in new block

I think you are doing single transaction at a time and before doing another transaction the time out is getting expired, try doing multiple transactions at a time